# BottomAppBar FabCradleMargin becoming less, almost flat, when BottomAppBar returns from being hidden

Tags: android, android-button, floating-action-button, android-bottomappbar

I am having an issue with my FabCradleMargin becoming less, almost flat, inside my Bottom App Bar when navigating through my app and scrolling up/down while hideonScroll is set to true. When the BottomAppBar hides from the screen, it returns resized under the Floating action Button. Must be a glitch in the new  Android Material Components. Has anyone else been experiencing this issue. If so, what suggestions do you have to fixing it.

[image: Before Image]

and

[image: After Image]

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_list" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/blue500"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_select_camera" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this problem as well. In my case it depended on the way I tried to hide the `BottomAppBar` and the `FloatingActionButton`. This is what I had first (Kotlin):

```
private fun showBottomNavigationBar(barVisibility: Boolean, fabVisibility: Boolean) {
    navView.visibility = if (barVisibility) BottomAppBar.VISIBLE else BottomAppBar.GONE
    fab.visibility = if (fabVisibility) FloatingActionButton.VISIBLE else FloatingActionButton.GONE
}
```

And this is what fixed it:

```
private fun showBottomNavigationBar(barVisibility: Boolean, fabVisibility: Boolean) {
    navView.visibility = if (barVisibility) BottomAppBar.VISIBLE else BottomAppBar.GONE
    if (fabVisibility) fab.show() else fab.hide()
}
```

So instead of hiding the `FloatingActionButton` with the visibility property, I used the **`hide()`** and **`show()`** methods of the `FloatingActionButton`.